# « Les moteurs choisis l’ont été parce que [...] »

Tags: participe-passé, auxiliaires

Ici, est-ce qu'`été` est invariable? S'agit-il d'une exception à la règle de l'accord du participe passé accordé avec l'auxiliaire avoir?

Selon ce qu'on m'a enseigné, je me pose la question: « Les moteurs ont été quoi? » Choisis, qui serait considéré comme un adjectif/attribut placé avant  le verbe, et donc la logique ferait qu'on mettrait un `s` à `été`. Mais je n'ai jamais vu `été` avec un `s` dans ce type de contexte.

Comment: *Été* n'est en fait pas le verbe, mais l'auxiliaire. Le verbe est omis (c'est *choisir*), il s'agit d'une ellipse pour éviter la répétition.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ah oui évidemment, cela ferait du sens. J'aurais accepté si ç'avait été une réponse. :)

Comment: De fait, je ne crois pas qu'il existe une construction où il est possible d'accorder le participe passé d'*être*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La phrase pourrait être :

> Les moteurs choisis ont été choisis parce que ...

C'est un peu lourd comme phrase, on élide donc le deuxième «choisis» qui se transforme en «l'».

«Été» n'est donc pas le verbe et ne s'accorde pas.